# Intellij-idea gradle sub-module keeps forgetting root project dependency

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I have two gradle projects defined like so

```
apiclient (root)
  | src\
  | build.gradle
  |--- android (module)
         | src\
         | build.gradle
```

These projects are not on maven, yet, and the module apiclient.android depends on the root module (apiclient).

I keep adding apiclient using the project structure... -> dependency dialog and the reference keeps getting removed from the .iml file whenever I click refresh in the gradle tool window.

how can I keep the child module from forgetting the parent module dependency?

edit: as requested the build.gradle files.

**apiclient build.gradle**

```
group 'emby.apiclient'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.11'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    compile 'org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.3.0'
}
```

**apiclient.android build.gradle**

```
group 'emby.apiclient'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.11'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.16'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.1.0'
    compile 'emby.apiclient:apiclient:1.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

The last line `compile 'emby.apiclient:apiclient:1.0-SNAPSHOT'` is underlined red in the gradle project window. I've tried `compile project 'apiclient'` as well and the outcome is unchanged.

**settings.gradle**

```
rootProject.name = 'apiclient'
include 'android'
findProject(':android')?.name = 'emby.apiclient.android'
```

Comment: Are you not managing the dependency in gradle, can you show your build.gradle files?

Comment: updated with build.gradle files.

Comment: You need to include your subprojects in the settings.gradle file to let gradle now it is building a multi project build

Comment: Both projects are listed in the settings.gradle.

Comment: What is `appclient.android`, is it a folder named that way?

Comment: Oops the tree reference is a typo, the folder is named android The project shows up as `android [emby.apiclient.android]` in the project window

Answer (score 0):

In the /android build.gradle file, you need to add `compile project(":apiclient")` to your dependency list.  I found out the hard way that IntelliJ's "Do you want to add a dependency to classpath" dialog only adds it to the .iml file, which isn't run as part of the build.